# reload web page only when size of page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reload

I have problem with reloading page, iam writing a site using RWD and media queries for desktop and tablet/mobile layout. And i have one page where i use google maps. My client want me to refresh page if he resize window from desktop size to mobile (i tried to tell him this is rather dumb idea but he didnt listen). Desktop displays all map with markers, but for tablets and mobile layout is different, i use accordion/list to display list of countries. when you click on one element form accordion he expands showing info from google maps windowinfobox. and the problem is when i use only media query ofcourse it change layout but all elements on the accordion are expanded, but it must be hide and only if you click then they expand, if i refresh page everyting is ok, problem is with resize page. i tried use window.resize(function(){location reload}); and its work perfectly with resize, but on mobile devices every touch couses relouding. so i want to write a function that reload page only when window size change from xxx to yyy if they cross the border 1024px., because then my accordion will display perfectly.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Look into responsive layouts, css media queries.

Comment: If you want to do what I think, you better learn how to use @media-query (css)

Comment: Like others have suggested.. Media queries is what you'd need. But to answer your question. You could find width of the screen like width = $(window).width(); And based on that you could do a window.reload().

Comment: I suspect this is a [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): are you trying to ask help for an attempted solution instead of asking for another problem?

Comment: sounds like you are trying to deal with the situation that someone with a large monitor would resize it to the size of a mobile device. why? who does that? use a emulator/device etc for mobile testing

Comment: I know is stupid but it is for client and i told him that normal people woudnt do this, resize on desktop to mobile phone window width, but he want it and i must do it. and i know how to use media queries and i did, but one element is google api and it doesnt listen to customize widhout refresh

Comment: I think it's better if you tell which google api you're talking about, describe the actual problem and why a reload should be needed.

Comment: what api? is that the real question? using some api on resize?

Comment: I was just writing that too, why not give us the real problem? Im sure there is a much better chance of someone here coming up with a proper solution than just you thinking there is no way around this Google API problem.

Comment: i use google maps and when on desktop are markers with map on mobile must be only customize markers like list/ accordion, when you click on them they display hiddne div width information from info window box from api

Comment: and the problem is what i wrote how can i reload page only when size of window change from one to one, border is 1024

Comment: @Karolina Change your question (or delete this one and create a new one) and give us a detailed picture of what the problem is. Giving us a demo is always a great idea too and will get the problem solved faster.

Comment: because if i refresh page is ok, but if i resize maps hidden, marker hidden but every element in accodion/list are shown, expanded, but i want it to be hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this is what you want.

```
$(function(){
 var width = $(window).width();
 var screen = "";
 if(width < 1024 && width >640){
  screen = "small";
 } else if(width>1024) { screen = "big"; }
 $(window).resize(function(){
  var cur_width = $(window).width();
  if(cur_width<1024 && cur_width>640 && screen == "big"){
   location.reload(); 
  } else if(cur_width >1024 && screen == "small"){
   location.reload();
 }
}
}
```